# iTunes cannot connect to Apple ID Server

Tags: itunes, apple-id

This is my first post to this exchange.  Being a programmer, I'm a huge stackexchange user and always get my answer so hopefully I will have success here.  Apple support stinks.

On windows 7 64bit.

My itunes was working fine and was in mist of purchasing songs, but could not verify my credit card details at checkout and then some error occurred.  I restarted and plugged in my iphone and then itunes said it could not connect to iphone until upgrading to new itunes version.  Well, I've used the iphone/itunes version before so I knew this was BS.  Long story short, I upgraded and now it cannot connect to Apple ID Server.  I downgraded version and same thing.

What's really strange is that my iCloud connects just fine.

I went through all the checks Apple suggests...the connection, the winsock, disable firewall, system date, etc, etc...and nothing seems to fix it.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

I know I'm using windows, so don't be hate'n.  I am bootcamping on imac so I'm not all bad. lol.

Answer (score 1):

After some time, I came back to this and tried some other things and got my iTunes connecting again.

On my Windows side, I use GData for my security and it has firewall settings, min-max.  I always keep it on max for tight security, but I tried lowering it to one below max and that worked.  Oddly, when I disabled firewall altogether, that did not work for me.  Also, sometimes I have to lower setting to two below max to get iTunes to connect.  Very strange, but it works.

What is really strange, is that I could not connect on my MAC side either, which is not running GData.

I got a work around and I'm fine with that.

I hope this helps someone else.